# mysql stored function error code: 1415 not allowed to return a result set from a function

Tags: mysql

I got the code to work until I added the if statement in. After that, I keep getting an error.

```
delimiter //
create function fTest_demo (myname varchar(20))
returns varchar(200)
begin
declare output varchar(200) default '';
select cid into output from dreamhome.Courses where name like concat('%',myname,'%');
if (output is null or output = '') then
  select 'Please input a valid string.' as message;
end if ;
return output;
end ;
//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: in `select cid into output`, you are getting more than one row. `INTO` clause will fail with error, as it expected one or zero rows only. Also, function returns a scalar output only

Comment: i see the issue is that the query will match more than 1 row and try to put it into output and it can't do that